# getting a value from an array in model

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model

I need a value of an array in model to compare with another value.How can I get it?
this is my code in model:

```
function get_order(){
$this->db->select('order');
$this->db->order_by('order','desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query=$this->db->get('section');
```

I need the last order record from $query.I tried this code but it does not show anything .

```
echo $query['order'];
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function get_order()
{
    $result =  $this->db->select('order');
                        ->order_by('order','desc');
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->get('section')
                        ->row();

    return $result->order;
}
```

this function will return the **`order`**.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Providing that your query is correct this will work.

```
function get_order(){
    $this->db->select('order');
    $this->db->order_by('order','desc');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query=$this->db->get('section');

    $aRow = $query->row_array();

    return $aRow['order'];
}
```